# Input repeat between Edit Text Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here is my problem, I have two Edit Text one with a maximum value of 2 digit and the other accept all values. But when I type, in the first Edit Text the values repeat again in the second and start to write with the two values from the first. Any answer how to stop from appear the values in the second Edit Text, that belong to the first?

Here is the code:

```
            if (inStr.equals("0")) {
               inStr = inDigit;
            } else {
               inStr += inDigit;

               int maxLength = 2;
               InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
               FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
               editX.setFilters(FilterArray);                  
               editX.setText(inStr);              
            }

            if(inStr1.equals("0")){
                   inStr1 = inDigit;
               }
            else{
                inStr1 += inDigit; 

                          editY.requestFocus(); 

                          editY.setText(inStr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to tell the context of your code but this line looks to be the culprit:

```
editY.setText(inStr1);
```

Just remove that line or change it to `editY.setText("")` to make sure its empty if you want.